# I want to redirect url from SEO. How can I rewrite All my URLs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, url-rewriting

How can i change my SEO result URL to my new Urls? I am using IIS 7. Is there any configuration to rewrite URLs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly clear how your scenario looks like but my best guess is that you want to rewrite URLs like `http://example.com/article?id=123&title=foo` to sth. more SEO friendly like `http://example.com/article/123/foo` with a HTTP response status code [301 Moved Permanently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301).

Have a look at [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) for IIS and this blog post for details:

- [Introduction to URL Rewriting using IIS URL Rewrite Module and Regular Expressions](http://www.domagojsalopek.com/Details/Introduction-to-URL-Rewriting-using-IIS-URL-Rewrite-Module-and-Regular-Expressions/26/CommentPage)